# Linux: wake_up and sleep_on functions

Tags: linux-kernel, wait, embedded-linux, waithandle, time-wait

I am trying to learn how to program loadable kernel modules for linux. I was wondering if anyone could tell me what the functions `sleep_on` and `wake_up` do?

In examples I am looking at `&WaitQ` is always passed into them and

```
static DECLARE_WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD(WaitQ);
```

is declared at the top of the module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a task in the kernel arrives at a point where it wants to use resource and it gets told `the resource is currently used by another task`, it can decide to go sleep saying `wake me up when the resource is available again`. That's basically the deal with sleep_on and wake_up. See here for an explanation in detail: http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/Linux_Kernel_Module_Programming_Guide/x1032.html